# Is asp net framework 4.5 code first approach possible?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, frameworks

Is ASP.NET framework 4.5 code first approach possible? I need to downgrade my project that I developed in .NET Core 6.0 to .NET 4.5 version. I created this project with the code first approach. Can we use migration code first in 4.5 version? I couldn't find any documentation about it. Thanks in advance for your help.What naget package versions can I use

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the asp.net 4.5 is totally different framework with .net 6. The .net 6 is asp.net core, but asp.net 4.5 is the old one which could only running at the Windows server.  You couldn't directly downgrade the version from 6 to 4.5, you need to development all the codes again.

> Can we use migration code first in 4.5 version?

Asp.net 4.5 also support EF code first, you could use the EF's package to run it. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/code-first-approach-in-mvc-5/).